# How to fix jagged font Google Chrome in OSX

Tags: macos, google-chrome, fonts

I noticed that large text looks jagged in Chrome (in OSX) but not in Safari or Firefox.

In Chrome:
[image]

In Safari and in Firefox: 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue turned out to be related to Mojave disabling sub-pixel aliasing. The quickest solution is to turn off `chrome://settings "Use hardware acceleration when available"`, as indicated in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55648194/how-to-prevent-large-fonts-from-looking-jagged-in-chrome-osx)